# How can I bypass the error "Could not load file or assembly XX" for libraries in the shared code that do not support Mac platform

Tags: macos, xamarin.forms

Can anyone advise on how we can bypass the error `"System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly XX"` for libraries in the `.NetStandard` shared project that do not support Mac platform such as `PCLCrypto`, causing the Mac app to fail on start-up at `NSApplication.Init()`. I want to keep the libraries in the shared code to use in Android and iOS.

I can put platform checks in the code to replace the plugin functionality that does not support Mac but I'm not sure how to get past this error.

Answer (score 0):

In the shared library .csproj, assuming your NuGet packages are listed inside`<PackageRefrence>` tags add the following condition to all packages you want to omit:

```
<PackageReference Include="PCLCrypto" Condition="$(TargetFramework.StartsWith('Xamarin.Mac'))" Version="2.0.1"/>
```